# How do I find out why a package (GPAC) has been removed from ubuntu?

Tags: apt

having recently upgraded to 23.10 I notice the apt package GPAC (universe) has been dropped.
Is there somewhere I should be able to look to find out why, and any other comments such as if it is likely to return etc ??

I've had a hunt around https://packages.ubuntu.com and couldn't find where I would see why it was removed, although interestingly I did find that it seems to be going to be included in 24.04 (LTS noble) which was a little surprising ... ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/gpac ) given it's removal from 23.10.

Is it possible that it's removal from 23.10 is an oversight given it's apparent presence in 24.04 ?

TIA
Pugelarouge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**: Debian is in the process of removing (dropping) `gpac` from their repositories. It's a slow, deliberate process. That's why Ubuntu did not pick up gpac for 23.10. Expect gpac to be dropped from 24.04 before release.

The package at Debian is currently unmaintained. Any community member(s) willing to learn the skills and process can resurrect `gpac` and return it to both Debian and Ubuntu. Start your journey at https://mentors.debian.net.

---

How to determine that the package is being dropped:

1. First place to look: Launchpad bug reports for the package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpac

   In this case, that comes up empty. No bug report mentions removal.
2. Second place to look: Package changelogs: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/g/gpac/

   In this case, another dry hole. No recent changelog mentions removal or replacement.
3. Third place to look: Debian package tracker: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gpac . Debian packages merge into Ubuntu every six months.

   Now we find a lot of clues. This package is an abandoned mess. It's old, insecure, and unmaintained. Ripe for removal. I would not recommend its use in current condition:

   [image]
4. The same Debian page has a handy link to Debian bugs.

   [image]

   And among those bug reports, we find [Debian Bug #1034732](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1034732):

   > Date: Sat, 22 Apr 2023 21:27:02 UTC

   > ...we've come to the
   > conclusion that gpac isn't suitable to be included in a stable release.

   > ...when [another package] has reached testing, gpac can be dropped.

   There is your action item.

Comment: Wonderful - thanks for the thorough answer, given the list of issues I'll just look to drop the MP4Box binary where I need it - or find the equivalent ffmpeg commend (I only use it to regenerate the index at 1 second intervals and move it to start of mp4 file - for streaming / progressive download with skipping)